# Get Indexes by coumn name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Sql-Server, and I have the below query which returns all columns that have a collation other than 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

```
select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLLATION_NAME <> 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
and COLLATION_NAME is not null;
```

I need to get also the Indexes on these columns so I can drop these indexes, modify columns, then recreate them.

My problem that I don't know how to get the indexes names for the columns returned from the query above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this helps you:

```
select object_schema_name(object_id), object_name(object_id), name
from    sys.indexes
where   type > 0
and object_name(object_id) in (
    select C.column_name
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C 
    where COLLATION_NAME is not null and COLLATION_NAME <> 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
)
```

Comment: It seems it working fine, but can I ask u what the condition type > 0 stands for?

Comment: means that the index is a Heap (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx).
If it solved your problem, please vote and mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select col.COLUMN_NAME,col.table_name,usg.CONSTRAINT_NAME as IndexName
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE usg
     on usg.TABLE_NAME=col.TABLE_NAME and usg.COLUMN_NAME=col.COLUMN_NAME
where col.COLLATION_NAME <> 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
and col.COLLATION_NAME is not null;
```

Comment: Isn't this returning the constraint name, not the index name?